# nginx ошибка 500

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

Переношу проект на ВМ и столкнулся с ошибкой 500 у nginx
вот лог:

```
2023/11/01 21:30:16 [crit] 3938#3938: *68 stat() "/root/frontend/index.html" failed (13: Permission denied)
```

[image: Расположение:]

Не могу понять как правильно настроить права.

ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Вы шутите? Какая нелегкая вас заставила сайт под /root выкладывать? Вы права на /root видели?

Comment: У меня крайне мало опыта в деплое на вм, подскажите, где почитать как сделать правильно

Comment: Расположите свой сайт в /var/www/html, если опыта мало. И отучитесь работать из-под root вообще. В будущем не пожалеете.

Comment: Только фронтэнд или бэкенд тоже?

Comment: "Бэкенд" - понятие очень растяжимое. Уберите всё из /root, как минимум.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, буду делать

Comment: Все заработало, еще раз спасибо

Comment: @void Я недавно начал свой путь, вы имеет ввиду, что даже разрабатывать какие-то вещи под  root'ом нельзя? ... просто я создаю коды, комичу и тд. Это не интернет проекты, делаю exe-файлы.

Comment: @Volk что вы имеете в виду, упоминая "разрабатывать какие-то вещи под root'ом нельзя"? Работать с операционной системой из-под root не рекомендуется для выполнения рутинных работ (внезапная тавтология).

Comment: @void, понял вас. Спасибо.  Этим ноутом пользуюсь только я. Поэтому и перешел на такую схему. Спасибо! Создам пользователя.